# Finding the minimum of $f(x) = 3\cos^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to find minimum and maximum of this function?
> $$f(x) = 3\cos^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1$$

I differentiated this function, and then I equalized it to $0$ because I thought that minimum must be somewhere where $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$. But with this, I only get the maximum of this function, but I need minimum.

$$f'(x) = -3\sin(2x) + \cos(x)$$

$$-3\sin(2x) + \cos(x) = 0 \implies \sin(x) = \dfrac{1}{6}$$
and maximum is $\dfrac{25}{12}$.

> But how to calculate the minimum?

Comment: cos(x)=0 is also a solution to f'(x)=0.  Where did 25/12 come from?

Comment: I just calculate 3cos^2(x)+sin(x)−1 when sin(x) = 1/6 and i get 25/12.

Comment: Setting $f(x)'=0$ should give you $-6 \cos x\sin x + \cos x = 0$. Note the LHS factors as $(1-6\sin x)\cos x$, so you have another factor to deal with.

Comment: if cos(x) = 0 then sin(x) = 1 and f(x) = 0 and in graphing calculator minimum is -2 and not 0

Answer (score 1):

**Without using calculus**

\begin{align}
 y=3\cos^2{x}+\sin{x}-1&=3(1-\sin^2x)+\sin x-1 \\
 &=-3\sin^2x+\sin x+2 \\
 &=\frac{25}{12}-\left(\sqrt3\sin x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\right)^2 \\
\end{align}

Clearly, the minima will be when $\left(\sqrt3\sin x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\right)^2$ is maximum, ie. when $\left|\sqrt3\sin x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\right|$ is maximum.

$\max\left(\left|\sqrt3\sin x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\right|\right)=\left|-\sqrt3-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\right|=\frac{7}{2\sqrt3}$

$\Rightarrow\min(y)=\frac{25}{12}-\left(\frac{7}{2\sqrt3}\right)^2=-2$

Answer (score 0):

So, here we go!

First of all, ypu have to compute first and second derivate:
$$f'(x)=-6 \cos x\sin x + \cos x$$
$$f''(x)=-6\cos(2x)-\sin(x)=6\sin(x)^2-\sin(x)-6$$
There is a bounch of teorems in analysis about finding local maxima and minima. In particular, if $f''(a)>0$ where $a$ is a zero of $f'(x)$ then $x=a$ is a local minimum.

Here, we are interested in: $$x_1=\frac{\pi}{2} \lor x_2=\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{6}) +k\pi \lor x_3=k\pi-\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{6})$$
Now, you can calculate $f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3)$ and see that the local minimum is $0$ and global minimum is $-2$.

**EDIT:**
Another method is simply calculate $x_1, x_2, x_3$, then evaluate the function at each point and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

$3\cos^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1 = 3(1-\sin^2 x) + \sin x - 1 = -3\sin^2 x + \sin x + 2$, so you want to find the minimum and maximum of $f(y) = -3y^2+y+2$ on $[-1,1]$.

The maximum occurs when $f'(y) = -6y+1=0$, so when $y = \sin x = \frac{1}{6}$; that maximum is $-\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{6} + 2 = \frac{25}{12}$. By comparing $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$, the minimum occurs at $y=-1$; that minimum is $-3(-1)^2-1+2 = -2$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\cos x=c,\sin x=s$ and note that

$f(x)=3c^2+s-1=3-3s^2+s-1=-3s^2+s+2=-3(s-\frac 16)^2+\frac {25}{12}$

So $f$ is minimum when $3(s-\frac 16)^2$ is maximum and this happens when $s=-1$, that is, when $x=2n\pi+\frac {3\pi}2, n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$

So minimum value of $f=\frac {25}{12}-3(\frac 76)^2=\frac{25}{12}-\frac{49}{12}=-2$